# Magento - Dynamic labels in customer.xml?

Tags: magento

In my customer.xml page I wish to change the label for the My Account link to the name of the customer. What would be the correct way to do this?

```
<customer_logged_in>
    <reference name="account.links">
        <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>My Account</label><url helper="customer/getAccountUrl"/><title>My Account</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>35</position></action>
        <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>Log Out</label><url helper="customer/getLogoutUrl"/><title>Log Out</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>40</position></action>
    </reference>
</customer_logged_in>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find solution to your problem by checking these posts. So please go through posts.

[additional parameters in magento's customer.xml layout file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7321364/additional-parameters-in-magentos-customer-xml-layout-file)

http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/230512/#t326018

Comment: Wow, how did I not find this? Thank you!